# Grouped Query (Pivot style?)

Tags: mysql

I thought this would be simple, but I'm struggling (might be Friday brains)

I have a table:

```
Staff      department     job_date       job             Hours
---------------------------------------------------------------
Chris      Software       2011-03-02     Writing Code    3
Chris      Software       2011-03-04     Holiday         7
Bob        QA             2011-03-02     Testing         4
Frank      Design         2011-03-11     Meeting         1
```

Now, I need a query that will "group" the results by day, based on whats in the job field, ie.. So I get a sum of hours spent per employee doing work and also for holidays:

**Resultset:**

```
Staff          Worked Hours       Holiday Hours  Department
---------------------------------------------------------------
Chris           3                  7              Software
Bob             4                  0              QA
Frank           1                  0              Design
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total           8                  7
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Chris

Comment: You say `"group" the results by day` but seem to be only grouping by employee. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that date column... That was only for getting entries for a particular month... You can ignore it for this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  department, staff,
        SUM(IF(job = 'Holiday', 0, hours)) AS work_hours,
        SUM(IF(job = 'Holiday', hours, 0)) AS holiday_hours
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        department, staff WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select staff,
       sum(case when job='holiday' then 0 else hours end) `Worked Hours`,
       sum(case when job='holiday' then hours else 0 end) `Holiday Hours`,
       department
from tbl
group by staff, department
```